# package diff tracking in opensuse

Tags: opensuse

I'm interested in viewing the commits made to the dhcpcd daemon package in opensuse 11.2 online. Id like to view information like commit messages, diff etc.

If such a system does not exist, it would be good enough to have a Changelog and different versions of the dhcpcd package for opensuse 11.2.

Thanks!

[EDIT] Figured it out, so I've added an answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! [build.opensuse.org](http://build.opensuse.org) was exactly what I was looking for!